# Debugging a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void binary(int n)
   {
      int bin=0;
      if(n!=0) 
      {
           bin=n%2;
           binary(n/2);
      }
      printf("%d",bin);
   }

   void main()
   {
      int a;
      printf("Decimal value: ");
      scanf("%d",&a);
      binary(a);
   }
```

When I tried to run above code, it outputs the binary value of the decimal number **a** preceding with one **0**. As I have used **recursive function** here, it also puts the initial value of **bin** (**i.e. 0**) on stack and prints that **0** as well. But I want to display only binary values not that preceding **0**.

I would be glad if anyone suggest me how to make this function not to store that initial value of **bin** on stack.

Comment: this will run forever because you aren't decrementing n at all.

Comment: @FaddishWorm: he's doing `n / 2` as the argument.

Comment: @FaddishWorm Nop,binary(n/2) call makes n decrementing by half. and i have used (n==0) as base condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void binary(int n)
{
       bin=n%2;
       if(n/2!=0)
         binary(n/2);

  printf("%d",bin);
}
void main()
{
   int a;
   printf("Decimal value: ");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   binary(a);
}
```

Since it checks whether n/2 == 0 **before** calling binary() it never prints the intial 0.